# How to implement regressors in a Hierarchical Series in R, with the Fable package?

Tags: r, time-series, fable-r

I am new to exploring the fable package, and I was wanting to implement Regressors in a Hierarchical Time Series model. How should the Dimensionality of the data be? Should there be an additional column inside the `tsibble` object? For example, in an ARIMA model. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach for modelling hierarchical data with exogenous regressors is the same as modelling regular data. The exogenous regressors should be a column of the tsibble object used to estimate the model, for each node in the hierarchy.

The code below shows how a simple hierarchy (`T = M + F`) can be modelled with a dynamic regression model (ARIMA with xreg). Note that the exogenous regressors are just white noise here, but you would use some real data here.

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(dplyr)
my_data <- as_tsibble(cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)) %>% 
  aggregate_key(key, value = sum(value)) %>% 
  # Add the regressor (if you have this in your data, could aggregate it above)
  # If the data is pre-aggregated, specify which keys are <aggregated> with agg_vec().
  mutate(my_xreg = rnorm(nrow(.)))
my_data
#> # A tsibble: 216 x 4 [1M]
#> # Key:       key [3]
#>       index key          value my_xreg
#>       <mth> <chr*>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 1974 Jan <aggregated>  3035  -1.87 
#>  2 1974 Feb <aggregated>  2552   1.93 
#>  3 1974 Mar <aggregated>  2704  -0.420
#>  4 1974 Apr <aggregated>  2554   0.332
#>  5 1974 May <aggregated>  2014  -1.10 
#>  6 1974 Jun <aggregated>  1655   1.22 
#>  7 1974 Jul <aggregated>  1721   1.68 
#>  8 1974 Aug <aggregated>  1524  -1.46 
#>  9 1974 Sep <aggregated>  1596   0.620
#> 10 1974 Oct <aggregated>  2074  -0.505
#> # … with 206 more rows
my_data %>% 
  model(ARIMA(value ~ my_xreg))
#> # A mable: 3 x 2
#> # Key:     key [3]
#>   key                        `ARIMA(value ~ my_xreg)`
#>   <chr*>                                      <model>
#> 1 fdeaths      <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,1,1)[12] errors>
#> 2 mdeaths      <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,2)(0,1,2)[12] errors>
#> 3 <aggregated> <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,2)(2,1,0)[12] errors>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much man, very clear example, this is an incredible package.

Comment: Dear Mitchell could I ask you to please take a look at this similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151618/incorporating-external-regressor-in-a-hierarchical-grouped-time-series