# Incorporating external regressor in a hierarchical/ grouped time series

Tags: r, time-series, fable-r

Fellow contributors,

I have been working with a hierarchical time series, relating to a set of identical products in a number of stores. For this purpose when we aggregate the data set based on 2 attributes like "store" and "product_type" in my case, we should then aggregate the target variable which is "demand" for every individual product for every group or hierarchy.
What I would like to do is add another categorical variable to my model let's say "Dynamic Harmonic Regression" as I am using weekly time series. However, I don't know how I should include it when my external variable is a categorical variable with 4 levels. I would like to know how I could aggregate this or whether there is anything I could do about it.
Here you can find a small reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(fpp3)
library(readxl)
library(fable.prophet)
library(feasts)

store <- c(rep('st1', 8), rep('st2', 8))
product_type <- c(rep('type1', 4), rep('type2', 4), rep('type1', 4), rep('type2', 4))
products <- c(rep('A', 2), rep('B', 2), rep('C', 2), rep('D', 2), 
              rep('A', 2), rep('B', 2), rep('C', 2), rep('D', 2))

demands <- c(round(sample(c(1:100), 16, replace = TRUE)))
external_reg <- c(sample(c('red', 'green', 'blue'), 16, replace = TRUE))
date_week <- rep(1:4, 4)
date_year <- rep(2019:2022, 4)

my_data <- tibble(date_year, date_week, store, product_type, products, demands, external_reg)

my_data %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(paste0(date_year, "-01-01")) + weeks(date_week - 1)) %>%
  mutate(Week = yearweek(Date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(store, product_type), index = Week) %>%
  aggregate_key(store * product_type, Demand_Agg = sum(demands))
```

Clearly the external regeressor should be a column in my `tsibble`:

```
# A tsibble: 36 x 4 [53W]
# Key:       store, product_type [9]
       Week store        product_type Demand_Agg
     <week> <chr*>       <chr*>            <dbl>
 1 2019 W01 <aggregated> <aggregated>        188
 2 2020 W02 <aggregated> <aggregated>        142
 3 2021 W02 <aggregated> <aggregated>        259
 4 2022 W03 <aggregated> <aggregated>        186
 5 2019 W01 st1          <aggregated>         89
 6 2019 W01 st2          <aggregated>         99
 7 2020 W02 st1          <aggregated>         52
 8 2020 W02 st2          <aggregated>         90
 9 2021 W02 st1          <aggregated>         95
10 2021 W02 st2          <aggregated>        164
# … with 26 more rows
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external regressor column (`external_reg`) has been dropped from your output because you have not specified how it should be aggregated. Given that it is a discrete variable, it might be tricky to aggregate the data in a way that keeps this information. How you choose to aggregate this is up to you, and may depend on the model you want to use. If you had a continuous variable like temperature, you may want to compute the average temperature.

For example, if you wanted to keep the first value of `external_reg` you would aggregate it with `aggregate_key(<tsibble>, store * product_type, Demand_Agg = sum(demands), external_reg = first(external_reg))`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

my_data <- structure(list(date_year = c(2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2021L, 2022L), date_week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), store = c("st1", "st1", "st1", 
"st1", "st1", "st1", "st1", "st1", "st2", "st2", "st2", "st2", 
"st2", "st2", "st2", "st2"), product_type = c("type1", "type1", 
"type1", "type1", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type1", 
"type1", "type1", "type1", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type2"
), products = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"), demands = c(45, 12, 70, 66, 
77, 6, 27, 52, 8, 73, 70, 27, 84, 100, 79, 51), external_reg = c("blue", 
"green", "red", "blue", "green", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", 
"blue", "green", "green", "red", "green", "blue", "green")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))

my_data %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(paste0(date_year, "-01-01")) + weeks(date_week - 1)) %>%
  mutate(Week = yearweek(Date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(store, product_type), index = Week) %>%
  aggregate_key(store * product_type, Demand_Agg = sum(demands), external_reg = first(external_reg))
#> # A tsibble: 36 x 5 [53W]
#> # Key:       store, product_type [9]
#>        Week store        product_type Demand_Agg external_reg
#>      <week> <chr*>       <chr*>            <dbl> <chr>       
#>  1 2019 W01 <aggregated> <aggregated>        214 blue        
#>  2 2020 W02 <aggregated> <aggregated>        191 green       
#>  3 2021 W02 <aggregated> <aggregated>        246 red         
#>  4 2022 W03 <aggregated> <aggregated>        196 blue        
#>  5 2019 W01 st1          <aggregated>        122 blue        
#>  6 2019 W01 st2          <aggregated>         92 blue        
#>  7 2020 W02 st1          <aggregated>         18 green       
#>  8 2020 W02 st2          <aggregated>        173 blue        
#>  9 2021 W02 st1          <aggregated>         97 red         
#> 10 2021 W02 st2          <aggregated>        149 green       
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mitchell for you answer. I understand, how to aggregate the categorical variable here was main question, that's why I didn't add it here. So does it suggest that external variable should be a continuous variable to be useful in this case?

Comment: Just one more question for me to understand this. Based on `store * product_type` and my weekly time series, each aggregation is calculated for each PRODUCT TYPE - STORE combination per WEEK, am I right?

Comment: Yes, your time variable is unchanged in this aggregation. `store * product_type` will consider aggregates by total, by `store`, by `product_type` and by the interaction of `store` and `product_type` (your current data). You need to think of what your categorical variable should be if aggregated (possibly NA, and only used at the bottom level?).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. We all owe you and Dr. Hyndman a lot for all of your efforts and materials. My categorical variable is `NA` for most of the products meaning it does not exist. So I thought I may turn it to a binary in a way if any category exists for a set of products in a particular week or not. With this assumption I got lower RMSE and MASE comparing to exclusion of external variable. So I think it could be legitimate.

Comment: But still I get this error `Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `Promotion_AggYes`  `. I read in rstudio community that Dr. Hyndman mentioned it could be because the external regressor must have been a constant.

Comment: Without the data it's difficult to identify why the regressors are rank deficient. However one possibility is that some of your models have `Promotion_AggYes` as all the same value (such as NA). If this is the case, then these variables should not be included in the model for those series.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again Mitchell. I changed my external variable to a numeric one, so that I could use `mean` as my aggregation function. But there are some `0`s in my variables that I replace with a very small numbers like `0.001` now the problem of rank deficiency has been solved and I see a reduction in `RMSE` like from `1200` to `900`. Do you think this could be a legitimate solution this way?

Comment: I'm not sure why replacing 0s would fix your rank deficiency problem, the better approach would be to estimate different models for series which don't have useful exogenous information.

Comment: I understand it may sound strange, but still I don't get any warning regarding rank deficient, whether in dynamic harmonic regression, prophet model or regression with fourier series. You are suggesting that I totally discard exogenous regressor? because unfortunately it is the subject of my thesis.

Comment: I would try removing exogenous regressors for series which it isn't useful for. Based on your improved RMSE, I imagine that some/many of these series are benefiting from the use of exogenous regressors.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you Mitchell, it was such an honor to have talked to you about it. I will do exactly as you suggested, and I really appreciate your comments. Except for Prophet model I had a considerable improvements on other models, still I kinda think the use of external variable is much trickier than it seems and no wonder that there hasn't been much literature about it in hierarchical forecasting.

Comment: Yes, exogenous regressors are tricky with time series! From data availability, to needing a good idea about how they behave in the future to be able to forecast with them. Ensuring they are available across aggregations in hierarchies and time makes it even trickier.